# Form Handling with Lambda-AWS

Tags: python, html, aws-lambda

I am trying to build a Lambda that displays a simple html form, where you fill your name (Mary for example) and the output should be "welcome Mary" but I dont know how to do it without .php

some information:

1.i am using python.

2.the first if (==GET) works fine.

3.action="lambda's URL", omitted in the code below.

4.my problem is on the second if(==POST).I dont know how to collect form data after submitting my HTML form.

Thanks in advance;)

here is the code:

```
import json
  
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
   
    if event['requestContext']['http']['method'] == 'GET':
        
        content='''
        <html>
        <body>

        <form action="my lambda's URL here" method="POST">
        Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
        
        <input type="submit">
        </form>

        </body>
        </html>

        '''
    
    if event['requestContext']['http']['method'] == 'POST':
    
        content='''
        <html>
        <body>

        <p>
        "I would like to see:"Welcome Mary" here but  i don't know how!
        </p>
        

        </body>
        </html>

        '''
         
   
    
    
    
    
    
    # TODO implement
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code you're accessing parts of the request like the HTTP method.

The event actually holds a heap of different bits of information about the request. You can see an example in the [Lambda developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html).

I would suggest printing out the entire event to start with while you get used to the format. Then work out how to access the form data.

Comment: Thank you @Mark Sailes for your answer. I will take a look at the Lambda developer guide.